# Connect nginx reverse proxy to application insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a simple nginx reverse proxy (which I am newbie on) configured as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass ${URL};
    }
}
```

This proxy is in a docker container and deployed to an Azure App Service. I connected the App Service to an Application Insights (AI) instance via Azure Portal. However the AI is empty: 0 log entries.
Is there a way to monitorize the requests with AI without having to add code to the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a monitoring for NGINX is an important part of maintaining website operations. If you check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/nodejs-virtual-machine-vm/azure-monitor-application-insights-nodejs-expressjs-code) Microsoft document then you would find that it's easy to view logs for monitoring NGINX deployed in VM. But it's not same for the case of Container App Service, here you would need [Container Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-overview).

You should try using Azure Monitor with NGINX in your case. **Azure monitor integrates the capabilities of Log Analytics and Application Insights for end-to-end monitoring of applications that include NGINX**. Check this [How to query logs from Container insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-log-query) document for more information.

There are also other monitoring systems out there suitable for the task; the first step, however, is to enable metric collection in NGINX. Check this [Monitoring NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/blog/monitoring-nginx/) document for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As far as I could see, Container Insights does not apply to App Services. On the solution I have, the docker container is stored in Container Registry and deployed to the App Service. Also the "Monitoring NGINX" suggestions don't include any monitoring tool with Azure resources, which would be the preference.